# Ultisnips dynamic tabstop generation with custom justified option

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

It seems possible to have ultisnips produce a dynamically sized array as specified here:

https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/examples/tabstop-generation/README.md

The array environment created however comes prespecified with `l`eft alignment on each of the columns as indicated in the example [here](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/examples/tabstop-generation/demo1.gif). The snippet code that produces this is:

```
post_jump "create_matrix_placeholders(snip)"
snippet 'arr(\d+),(\d+)' "LaTeX array" br
\begin{array}{`!p
orient = ""
for _ in range(0, int(match.group(1))): orient += "l"
snip.rv = orient`}
`!p
snip.rv = create_matrix(match.group(1), match.group(2), "&", "\t", "\\\\\\\\\n")
`$0
\end{array}
endsnippet
```

Is it possible to modify this snippet so that we only have `\begin{array}{|}` where `|` is the first placeholder stop `$1` so that the user can specify whether one needs `l`eft or `c` enter or `r`ight alignment for each column?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done by

1. adding a `$1` placeholder at `\begin{array}{|}`, and
2. starting the placeholders within the matrix/array from 2 and up.

The first can be done by modifying lines 3-6 with

```
\begin{array}{${1:`!p
orient = ""
for _ in range(0, int(match.group(1))): orient += "l"
snip.rv = orient`}}
```

and the second can be done by modifying the code for `create_matrix()` to take in an additional argument controlling the starting placeholder:

```
global !p
def create_matrix_placeholders(snip):
    # not shown

def create_matrix(cols, rows, sep, start, end, placeholder=1):
    res = ""
    # 
    for _ in range(0, int(rows)):
        res += start + f"${placeholder} "
        placeholder += 1
        for _ in range(0, int(cols) - 1):
            res += sep + f" ${placeholder} "
            placeholder += 1
        res += end
    return res[:-1]
endglobal
```

and modifying line 8 of the snippet given in the question with

```
snip.rv = create_matrix(match.group(1), match.group(2), "&", "\t", "\\\\\\\\\n", 2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried carefully replicating your code. However, it does not seem to work. Specifically, when I type genarr3x4, there is a bunch of `l`'s that get placed on top of the expanded snippet. Example can be seen https://imgur.com/a/dDag2KO

Comment: Here is the diff of the after (lhs) vs before (rhs) 
https://imgur.com/55xnvnK
https://imgur.com/gTKm1NG
to ensure I have implemented your suggestions exactly.

Comment: I got the same result that you did. It looks like the problem is with the implementation of the expansion of anonymous snippets.. Let me see if there is a workaround

Comment: Well thank you. I certainly appreciate the time and effort.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find a workaround.. The details did not work, but I'll leave the main idea here: Currently the snippet is supposed to expand as `genarr3x4` -> `\begin{array}{${1:lll}} { ` ... placeholders to be anonymously expanded ... `} \end{array}` -> `\begin{array}{${1:lll}} {  $2 & $3 ... } \end{array}`. This "double expansion" seems to mess up Ultisnips. Instead, empty the snippet before any anonymous expansion, ie. `genarr3x4` -> (get the value of nrow, ncol, and clear that current line) -> { anonymously expand into `\begin{array} ${1:lll} $2 & $3 ...` } all at once